# why does this code have no console output?

Tags: python

Below is the code I am working with and although there are no errors in the console output it still doesn't return anything there. Why is there no output with the code? Is there anything I need to change or fix. I think I imported the scanner correctly but there may be an issue with that. Thank you!

```
import sys
from scanner import Scanner
from functools import cmp_to_key

class Tweet:
    def __init__(self, tweeter, tweet, time):
        self.tweeter = tweeter[1:]
        self.tweet = tweet
        self.time = time
    def  __str__(self):
        return self.tweeter+" "+self.time
    def display(self):
        return self.tweeter+" " +self.tweet

def create_record(s):
    tweets = []
    tweeter = s.readtoken()
    tweet1count = 0

    while tweeter != "":
        tweet = s.readstring()
        t1 = Tweet(tweeter, tweet, s.readline())
        tweet1count += 1
        tweeter = s.readtoken()
        tweets.append(t1)
    return tweets

def read_records(file):
    s = Scanner(file)
    return create_record(s)

def is_more_recent(t1, t2):
    year, month, day, time = t1.time.split()
    month = ("0" + month)[-2:]
    day = ("0" + day)[-2:]
    timestamp1 = year + month + day + time
    year, month, day, time = t2.time.split()
    month = ("0" + day)[-2:]
    day = ("0" + day)[-2:]
    timestamp2 = year + month + day + time
    return timestamp1 > timestamp2

def merge_and_sort_tweets(tweets1, tweets2):
    tweets = tweets1 + tweets2
    cmp_items_py3 = cmp_to_key(is_more_recent)
    tweets.sort(key = cmp_items_py3)
    return tweets

def write_records(file, tweets):
    file = open(file, "w+")
    for t in tweets:
        file.write(str(t))

def main():
    print("Reading Files")
    tweets1 = read_records(sys.argv[1])
    tweets2 = read_records(sys.argv[2])
    tweet1count = len(tweets1)
    tweet2count = len(tweets2)
    if tweet1count > tweet2count:
        print("tweet1.txt contained the most tweets with" , tweet1count)
    elif tweet1count < tweet2count:
        print("tweet2.txt contained the most tweets with" , tweet2count)
    else:
        print("tweet1.txt contains ", tweet1count, "tweets. ")
        print("tweet2.txt contains ", tweet2count, "tweets. ")
    print("Merging files...")
    tweets = merge_and_sort_tweets(tweets1, tweets2)
    print("Writing file...")
    write_records(sys.argv[3], tweets)

    print("File writtem. Displying", min(5, len(tweets)),"earliest tweeters and tweets.")
    for i in range(min(5, len(tweets))):
        print(tweets[i].display())

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Comment: The `if` statement at the end should not be inside the `main()` function.

Comment: Because of that you never call the function.

Comment: where would be the right location to put it?

Comment: Exactly where it is, just not indented.

Comment: If you understand what it's doing, it should be obvious where it belongs.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do/419185#419185

Comment: When I put the `if` statement back it would say i have an error saying IndexError: list index out of range referring to the second line in `main()`

Comment: Your script expects two command line arguments. Did you provide those arguments when you ran it? What do you think `sys.argv[1]` means?

Comment: Ah thank you i was confused for a second